# Как изменить значение при нажатии на ячейку в таблице

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть функция которая позволяет при вводе массива нарисовать таблицу и еще функция которая позволяет задавать координаты в таблице и значение можно двигать , А как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на любую ячейку значение поменялось ?

```js
function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

  if(document.querySelectorAll('._Table').length > 0){
    for(var i = document.querySelectorAll('._Table').length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
      document.querySelectorAll('._Table')[i].remove(); 
    };
  };
  table.classList.add('_Table');
  
 
 tableData.forEach(function(rowData, i) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData, j) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.id=i+'_'+j
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var row = document.querySelector(".col1").value;
  var col = document.querySelector(".col2").value;
  var row_mas = [];
  var col_mas = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    var col_mas = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      col_mas.push(0);
    }
    row_mas.push(col_mas);
  }
  createTable(row_mas);
});

document.querySelector(".btn2").addEventListener("click", function() {
   var row = document.querySelector(".col3").value;
   var col = document.querySelector(".col4").value;
   var gell = document.getElementById(row+"_"+col);
   gell.innerHTML="1"
});
```

```css
 body {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}
th,td {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: white;
}
tbody {
  background-color: blue;
}
input {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="col1">
  <input type="text" class="col2">
   <button class="btn">Go</button>
   <br/>
   <input type="text" class="col3">
   <input type="text" class="col4">
   <button class="btn2">koordinats</button>
```

Comment: помогите ребят.

Comment: Вам нужно при нажатии изменить значение ячейки и всё? А на что менять?

Comment: Да ,(например на 2) на любое другое значение и чтобы цвет ячейки тоже поменялся

Comment: *А как сделать так чтобы при нажатии на любую ячейку значение поменялось ?* - Поменялось на что?

Comment: сейчас там стоит значение 0, а при нажатии стало например 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого нужно создать функцию нажатия и вызывать её при каждом создании таблицы

```js
function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');

  if (document.querySelectorAll('._Table').length > 0) {
    for (var i = document.querySelectorAll('._Table').length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      document.querySelectorAll('._Table')[i].remove();
    };
  };
  table.classList.add('_Table');


  tableData.forEach(function(rowData, i) {
    var row = document.createElement('tr');

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData, j) {
      var cell = document.createElement('td');
      cell.id = i + '_' + j
      cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
      row.appendChild(cell);
    });

    tableBody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

// Наше нажатие
function clickCell() {
  var cell = document.querySelectorAll('._Table td');
  for(var i = 0; i < cell.length; i++){
    cell[i].onclick = function() {
      this.innerHTML = 2;
      this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    };
  };
};

document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var row = document.querySelector(".col1").value;
  var col = document.querySelector(".col2").value;
  var row_mas = [];
  var col_mas = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    var col_mas = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < col; j++) {
      col_mas.push(0);
    }
    row_mas.push(col_mas);
  }
  createTable(row_mas);
  clickCell(); // Вызываем эту функцию
});

document.querySelector(".btn2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var row = document.querySelector(".col3").value;
  var col = document.querySelector(".col4").value;
  var gell = document.getElementById(row + "_" + col);
  gell.innerHTML = "1"
});
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}
th,
td {
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: white;
}
tbody {
  background-color: blue;
}
input {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="col1">
<input type="text" class="col2">
<button class="btn">Go</button>
<br/>
<input type="text" class="col3">
<input type="text" class="col4">
<button class="btn2">koordinats</button>
```

Применять функцию при каждом создании таблицы нужно потому, что если запустить только один раз, то к новым ячейкам она применяться не будет

Comment: `var cell = document.querySelectorAll('td');` Чуть-чуть вот эта строчка смущает. Надо ограничить `td` конкретной таблицей, а не со всего документа брать.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, подправил